# Building Breadcrumbs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a table that defines the possible categories in my website - fields look something like this:

```
  - id
  - name
  - parentID
```

The information is stored something like this:

```
+-----+------+----------+
| id  | name | parentID |
+-----+------+----------+
|  1  | pets |        0 |
+-----+------+----------+
|  2  | cats |        1 |
+-----+------+----------+
|  3  | dogs |        1 |
+-----+------+----------+
```

A `parentID` of 0 indicates that the category/page is on the home level. I'm looking for a way to quickly and easily generate the parent categories.

The first method that came to mind was a series of SQL queries, but I quickly realised that this would be insidiously resource intensive the more complicated the site got.

Reading through the mysql manual, I've seen that mysql can use loops and conditional statements, however I'm unsure how I'd put those into practice here.

Ideally, I'd like to have a single query that pulls up all directly related parent elements.

If I were looking at the Pets category, I would only see `home` because it's on the top level. As soon as I drill down (either into `cats`, `dogs` or a page under `pets`) then I should see `pets` on the bar - the same goes for subsequent child categories and pages.

What's the most efficient way to generate a list of categories using information stored in this fashion? If this question requires more clarification, please ask, and I will do my best to provide more information.

**Clarification**: This is part of a CMS - and as such, users are going to need the ability to make changes to categories on the fly. I've looked at several data storage schemes (such as nested sets) and they do not appear to lend themselves well to a simple form for making changes to navigation.

As such, any method needs to be easily a) understood by a user, and b) implemented easily to a user.

The categories are best described as folders on a PC, rather than tags. When you view any given category, you can see the immediate children of that category, as well as immediate child pages.

When you view a category or a page, the parent categories (but not itself are visible).

Example: I have *German Shepard* which resides under *dogs* which is under *pets*

```
When viewing *pets*:           Home
When viewing *dogs*:           Home -> Pets
When viewing *German Shepard*: Home -> Pets -> Dogs
```

Comment: You could use a stored procedure, which would utilize the "loops and conditional statements" you alluded to.  But really, SQL doesn't cope well with trees.  Consider storing values in a non-tree format (e.g. nested sets), or, if your data set is small enough, building your tree once from a single SELECT, and cache the result in APC, memcache, or even serialized in a single record in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using "nested sets" model instead: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

**Update** (based on clarification to the question): The nested sets model does not have to be (in fact I have a pretty hard time imagining why would it be) exposed to end users. All directory-style operations (adding a new folder / subfolder; moving folder to a different path, etc...) can be supported in nested sets model, though some are a bit harder to implement then others. The article I've linked to provides examples for both adding and deleting of (sub)folder.

Comment: I clarified my question a little bit - I'd like to use nested sets, however I believe it would be too difficult for users to visualise and thus implement through a control panel.

Comment: You could present the data however you wanted, and use nested sets behind the scenes.

Comment: Just like your users don't need to be able to write SQL queries for your app to be database-backed, they don't need to understand nested sets for you to be using nested sets under the hood.

Comment: The problem with nested sets is that there is a significant disconnect between the data and the representation of data to the user. Look at the graphic http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-5.png - how do you make something like that editable for a user to quickly and easily generate their website structure?

Comment: There is a "folder" diagram at the top of the article (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-1.png). That **IS** what both adjacency and nested sets models represent and that's what users would see.

Comment: I'll look at the article in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a stack or ordered set (ordered by how the user applied filters to their browsing) containing your breadcrumb, stored on the session?

I could see it getting grim when you started cross-querying, but sometimes data isn't hierarchical, but more of a soup of tags, and the above starts being your tag-soup clarification breadcrumb.

Most websites don't actually feature good (or any) tag soup drilling down. E.g., how many times have you been look at the sale CDs on a website, and wanted to drill down to just see the Metal CDs (for example), but clicking on the "Rock and Metal" link on the left took out to the top level metal category, instead of acting as a filter on your current browsing state.

So - is your problem actually a tag soup that you're applying a false hierarchy onto? Should you in fact be looking at automatic tag generation libraries that you can pass your items into, and tag lookup mechanisms? Okay, I'm sure your personal website won't be complex enough to ever require tag search, but in general terms, I think it is worth thinking about.

Comment: I would say that's not the problem. Perhaps tags isn't the best way to describe it. The categories function like folders on a PC. When you display a category, it shows you the categories that are immediately underneath your current level, as well as any pages in it.

Comment: That's fair enough, although file systems with managed proper hard links can act like a tagged lookup system. Just throwing it out there. Like looking for a recent word/image/foo document when you organise by project and you forgot what project it was in.